# Why my method not working? Please explain

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

[image]

> I want to know where I am wrong. I have got the answer by another method, but I wanted to know why my 1st method is not working.

[image]

Comment: if you want to make your question usefull for another site visitors I'll recommend to rename it to a better searchable way, like "how to find acceleration from given graph" or smth like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clearly readable but the first method seem to be wrong because you consider acceleration to be constant in this motion, but during constant acceleration $v\sim \sqrt{x}$ and your graph you can clearly see show that $v \sim x^2$, so acceleration is increasing during the motion and formula $v^2=v_0^2+2aS$ doesn't work.

But during the short time we can assume $v^2(t+\Delta t)=v^2(t)+2a(t)\Delta x$, so the formula
$$a=\dfrac{v^2(t+\Delta t)-v^2(t)}{2\Delta x}=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{dv^2}{dx}=\dfrac{vdv}{dx}$$
does work

Comment: Ooops . I got it why I am wrong this formula v^2=u^2+2aS is only for constant acceleration. Thanks for helping me